# How Android manage its resources?

Tags: android, resources

I pretty much put my question in the title..

I spend quite a time with Android lately, but I'm still confused about how Android manage its resources? What's the role of the R.java file? What's the role of the /res folder and subfolders?

Is there any good article that gives satisfactory answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Karla, Have you ever mailed out bulk mail for a non-profit organization? Well, I have. I had to send out letters and post-cards, and the only way the post office would give my organization a discount was if I placed all the postcards in one box and all the letters in another box (presorted according to the recipient's zip code). Essentially, that's what resources are, pre-sorted and pre-organized stuff. Now this doesn't mean that you won't be able to send out more letters and postcards later on (after the preprocessing and the compiling has been done), it's just that once the resources container is already packaged, you won't be able to include more stuff in that namespace anymore, and whatever you generate and send out after that will come at a standard cost (not the discount they initially gave you).

Answer (score 3):

You should start reading the documentation about Android on http://developer.android.com

The page about your question is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html

Comment: All the answers to your question are on the android developer documentation.  If you spend a few hours reading through it you'll answer all the questions you've posted

Comment: Then you should have understood the meaning of "Resources", at least I did.

Comment: great - then can you explain for me how the appt tool generates the R.java file? and why new resources cannot be added at runtime?

Comment: you can look at the sdk source code to see how the R file is generated.